# how to extract main text from html using Tika

Tags: html-parsing, apache-tika, boilerpipe

I  just want to know that how i can extract main text and plain text from html using Tika?

maybe one possible solution is to use BoilerPipeContentHandler but do you have some sample/demo codes to show it?

thanks very much in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample:

```
public String[] tika_autoParser() {
    String[] result = new String[3];
    try {
        InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File("/Users/nazanin/Books/Web crawler.pdf"));
        ContentHandler textHandler = new BodyContentHandler();
        Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
        AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
        ParseContext context = new ParseContext();
        parser.parse(input, textHandler, metadata, context);
        result[0] = "Title: " + metadata.get(metadata.TITLE);
        result[1] = "Body: " + textHandler.toString();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TikaException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The BodyContentHandler class doesn't use the Boilerpipe code, so you'll have to explicitly use the BoilerPipeContentHandler. The following code worked for me:

```
public String[] tika_autoParser() {
    String[] result = new String[3];
    try {
        InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File("test.html"));
        ContentHandler textHandler = new BodyContentHandler();
        Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
        AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
        ParseContext context = new ParseContext();
        parser.parse(input, new BoilerpipeContentHandler(textHandler), metadata, context);
        result[0] = "Title: " + metadata.get(metadata.TITLE);
        result[1] = "Body: " + textHandler.toString();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TikaException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;
}
```